# What is the Windows equivalent of this Mac Excel shortcut?

Tags: windows, macos, microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

I can't remember how I learned how to do this, but I'm 90% sure it's a built-in default shortcut for Mac Excel 2011.

Make a selection in your spreadsheet. Hit `option-tab` to move that selection to the right, `option-shift-tab` to move it to the left, `option-return` to move it down, and `option-shift-return` to move it up.

I can't find any documentation of this shortcut to know what it is called, so I could look up the Windows Excel 2010 equivalent. Does anyone know what this is called?

---

**Edit:** I noticed today that this can actually be used to **enter data into all of the selected cells**. In other words, you select some cells, start typing the data you want, and then `option-tab` or `option-return` to apply that data to all of the selected cells and select the next empty set of cells. Using `enter` instead of `return` will result in the data simple being entered into all cells without selecting the next group. So it appears as though the equivalent would be for something like "enter into all selected cells".

Comment: what do you mean by "move the selection to the right"? You mean if you select A2:B2 and you press option-tab then the selection will be B2:C2? Can you give some examples? I'm sure we can find it for you.

Comment: @guitarthrower If you start with A2:B2 and hit opt-tab, your selection will be C2:D2. It's pretty wild. Most often I'd use it by selecting a column like B6:B12, hit opt-tab to select C6:C12.

Comment: That's crazy. To my knowledge there is nothing built in, but it could be programmed via VBA to do something similar. Oddly enough, these shortcuts are not listed on the [Microsoft site](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/mac-excel-help/excel-keyboard-shortcuts-HA102927337.aspx) for the Mac version of Excel.

Comment: Ctrl+Enter has the same enter in all cells function on windows, but not the select next group of cells of the same size function. I suspect that on OS X two shortcuts actually overlap. I don't see any such shortcut documented on windows. Also the behavior you describe is not documented in the online Excel help for OS X.

Comment: Who knew that we Mac users were spoiled with secret keyboard shortcuts :-)